# How to pass a variable in ajax append function (into html element with razor)?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor

I need to pass the Id of a object into a html element (razor part), but it doesn't recognize it. Look like the Id is not in its scope, or something. Is there a way to pass the value into the razor part of my html element in the append function?

```
$.ajax({
        data: data,
        url: url + "?searchTerm=" + data

    }).success(function (response) {

        console.log(response);
        var table = $('#companyTable');
        var tBody = table.children('tbody');
        tBody.html("");
        var textbox = document.getElementById("searchBar");
        textbox.value = "";

        tBody.append(
            "<tr><td>" +response.CompanyName + " </td><td>" +
                       response.CompanyIdNumber + "</td><td>" +
                       response.CompanyTaxNumber + "</td><td>" +
           "<p><button onclick=\"location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Company", new { @id = response.CompanyId  })'\"> Edit</button></p>" +
                           "</td></tr>"
                );
            table.removeClass("hidden");
            var originalTable = $('#originalTable');
            originalTable.remove();

        }).error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do those things this way:

```
+ "<p><button onclick=\"location.href='@(Url.Action("Edit", "Company"))?id=" + response.CompanyId + "'\">Edit</button>"
```

Comment: This is really a nice one tho

Answer (score 0):

You are totally missing the concept of server-side rendering and browser execution. Consider this example, your server renders your js code, and just leaves all work to browser, then browser stars to execute Ajax request somehow(button click), when Ajax completed - you have a response value, but this value exists only inside browser context, so it doesn't make sense to pass value into razor, as it already done its work while rendering your file

Now, what to do? The simplest solution would be to hardcore Url of company edit by yourself, as razor simply doesn't know anything what's happening client-side, example:

```
location.href="/company/1/edit" //where 1 is id from Ajax request
```

Comment: Close, but I figured it out. You actually gave me a good idea and thank you for that. This is my solution:

"<p><button onclick=\"location.href='Company/Edit/" + response.CompanyId + "'\"> Edit</button></p>" 

Once again, thank you!

Comment: I usually don't prefer hard coded route paths, but if it avoids headaches - go for it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest complete solution is

```
public ActionResult WhateverMethod()
{
 // ....

  var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
  response.Url = Url.Action("Edit", "Company", new { @id = response.CompanyId  });

 // ....
}
```

And

```
tBody.append(
  "<tr><td>" +response.CompanyName + " </td><td>"
  + response.CompanyIdNumber + "</td><td>"
  + response.CompanyTaxNumber + "</td><td>"
  + "<p><button onclick=\"location.href='" + response.Url + "'\"> Edit</button></p>"
  + "</td></tr>");
```

Calling a Razor methods in JavaScript is going to cause you nothing but grief.

Comment: I realized that. I solved the problem, without razor :)
Here is my solution:
"<p><button onclick=\"location.href='Company/Edit/" + response.CompanyId + "'\"> Edit</button></p>"

Comment: That's good, but you're relying on a hard coded value.  If your app runs under a directory, because you aren't using the UrlHelper, the link will fail.

Comment: You're right, that's why I changed it. Now I'm using the solution Gene R posted and it works just fine

Comment: It's still *hard-coded* because you assume that the id will be the first parameter *all the time*.  If it changes, that code will also fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
response.CompanyId is considered as string , so try by concatenating it as below   
var a="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Company", new{@id='"+response.CompanyId+"'})'"
 response.CompanyId ( "<tr><td>" +response.CompanyName + " </td><td>" +
 response.CompanyIdNumber + "</td><td>" +
 response.CompanyTaxNumber + "</td><td>" +
 "<p><button onclick=\""+a +"\"> Edit</button></p>" + "</td></tr>")
```